# Getting intersection with sphere in three js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a little problem with my script for a rollover in three js.
It's working perfectly with cube, plane, cylinder etc... but I'm getting this with the sphere :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'copy' of null
```

I just don't understand why, the error is situated in Three.js on line 21 (condensed one).
Here's the important part of my script inside a mousemove event listener :

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (ev)
{
 if (ev.target == renderer.domElement) {
   var x = ev.clientX;
   var y = ev.clientY;
   var width = ev.target.width;
   var height = ev.target.height;

   var v = new THREE.Vector3((x/width)*2-1, -(y/height)*2+1, 0.5);
   projector.unprojectVector(v, camera);
   var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, v.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
   var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(controller.objects);
   if (intersects.length > 0) 
   {
      /*DO STUFF*/
   }
  }
 }
```

If you have a clue, it will be much appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without knowing a little more this will be hard to fix, can you make a jsFiddle or some live demo?